# Common patterns for styling a large website

Tags: css

Is there any common patterns for how to setup, create, store your CSS for large websites?

I have tried many different things that I have come up with on my own.

I've tried putting all layout (position, size, etc.) in 1 file while all decoration (color, background, etc.) in another so I can swap out styles easily without effecting layout. This becomes very tedious when every element is styled in multiple files.

I've tried coming up with one main CSS file, then any page that has different rules, gets its own CSS file for those rules. This eventually leads to other pages with the same "unique" rules, and always ends up with duplicate CSS (each page has its own CSS file defining what-should-be a shared style) making it harder to maintain.

Every CSS book, tutorial, or whatever I have ever read explains what CSS does and how to use it in the context of a single page or small site. I have a good understanding of that, but I never see any discussions on how to make a plan to style a large website with lots of inconstancies.

Is there a pattern/common practice I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

You should always keep in mind performance. Having one large file is optimal since it is only loaded once and can be subsequently cached, allowing other external resources to be loaded reducing the overhead of page load times substantially. Obviously it makes for a large file but through comments and indenting you should be able to group things together in a reasonable manner.

Alternatively you can keep them separate in your DEV environment and consider a build mechanism to combine them all into one file before deployment. That really gives the best of both worlds.

The only real need I've seen for separate CSS files is theming, accessibility and different styles for the medium (print, page etc...).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the big sites like for example Flickr, Facebook, Twitter or something like that. The best thing (in terms of speed), is to use one css file to store everything.
In terms of different rules for different sites, there is also a possibility to design "modular" - like

```
.redFontColor {
  color: #F00;
}

.smallFont {
  font-family: "Courier New", "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: .7em;
}

.alignedLeft {
  text-align: left;
}
```

And use it in HTML like that

```
<div class="alignedLeft">
  This will be <span class="smallFont redFont">small and red</span> - but this text will just be <span class="redFont">red</span>
</div>
```

There are quite a lot of sites which go like this ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You should always keep in mind:

- [Reusability](http://ifacethoughts.net/2007/12/09/reusability-and-non-semantic-names/)
- [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
- [W3C Standards](http://www.w3.org/standards/)
- [Cross-Browser Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-browser)
- [Performance](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

What i usually do is this:

I make one CSS file for the containers e.g. and another file for the individual styles (div, img, a link etc).

with containers i mean, the outline of your website, your website content e.g text goes insite it.

with styles i mean,  or   and the list goes on.

I hope this helped you, ill edit my post with a very good manual on this.(As soon as i find it).

PS. the book is free.

Answer (score 0):

We recently implemented something which we named "CSS compilation", which is something like what methodin has answered. Our compilation (done by the PHP backend) produces a single compiled css file for every module and thus a single CSS file is loaded at runtime. This gives us the liberty to define as many CSS files as we want without worrying about performance. For this we defined an array `$moduleCssrelation` containing module-CSS files relation in a config file of our project (module e.g. login, home etc. and the CSS files to be loaded for every module). Describing more details on that in the end because that is the core of the style-architecture.

This is the basic CSS plan that we used:-

1. Studied in detail all the modules noted style patterns/reusable components and saw that

   - the header section, footer section and a left menu are needed in every module
   - there are many modules which have a tabular display section of some lists at the center (leaving the common header,footer and left menu) and there are many modules which display some item details like user details page, class details page.
2. We had all the styles in a single file delivered to us by a team of designers. Then we fragmented the single CSS file into a number of fragments as per the style patterns as studied in the previous step. So, we created some files like -
3. `common.css`
   Containing header, footer, left menu styles
4. `listings.css`
   Containing all the style definitions for components appearing only in the listing pages.
5. `details.css`
   Like thedom has mentioned, if you have a `.detailsRedHeading` class which will be needed only in case of details pages, define it here.
6. Any extra styles - suppose many modules need a popup with its style, then put those styles inside a `popups.css` instead of defining those styles in `common.css` or any other file. Remember the liberty we have to define as many css files as we want.

**For ease of later theme changes**
I have never applied your idea of "I've tried putting all layout (position, size, etc.) in 1 file while all decoration (color, background, etc.) in another", but if it helps you, you can add that to this architecture. Break `common.css` into `common_layout.css`, `common_design.css` and similarly for others.

Also, make sure you do the maximum possible style reuse the first time. Avoid style declarations like this:-

```
.listingsBody
{
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  .. 
  some listing page styles
  ..
}

.detailsBody
{
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  .. 
  some details page styles
  ..
}
```

Instead have this:-

```
.siteMediumFont
{
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.detailsBody
{
  .. 
  some details page styles
  ..
}

.listingsBody
{
  .. 
  some listing page styles
  ..
}
```

I have seen that many designers do this. This habit in more complex cases can make things really difficult later.

**Details on compilation :-**

After we finish applying CSS changes, we run the compilation code which does the following:-

```
$moduleCssrelation = array("class_details"=> array("details","popups"));
```

Traverse the array `$moduleCssrelation` and create a compiled file from the contents of the css file names for every module.
e.g. If the `class_details` module needs files `details.css`,`popups.css`, then it creates a file `common-details-popups.css` which will also be loaded for `class_details` as well as any other module needing these two css files.